# How to create converter type function

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I am attempting to convert the object into the class that i made.
I can convert the object easily with this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar[] Bars;
}

object fooObject = assembly.CreateInstance(fooName);
Foo foo = (Foo)fooObject;

// Where assembly is System.Reflection.Assembly
// And I don't know why that I can't convert it directly like:
// Foo foo = (Foo)assembly.CreateInstance(fooName);
// @^ that code will always make all Bar in Foo.Bars disappear
```

So i was trying to make it short / more simple.
I want to make it just like this:

```
Foo foo = Converter.Convert(assembly.CreateInstance(fooName));
```

But how i can do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual type, then just:

```
SomeType typed = (SomeType)obj;
typed.MyFunction();
```

If you don't know the actual type, then: not really, no. You would have to instead use one of:

•reflection
•implementing a well-known interface
•dynamic
For example:

```
// reflection
obj.GetType().GetMethod("MyFunction").Invoke(obj, null);

// interface
IFoo foo = (IFoo)obj; // where SomeType : IFoo and IFoo declares MyFunction
foo.MyFunction();

// dynamic
dynamic d = obj;
d.MyFunction();
```